# SQL: Pinned rows and row number calculation

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-server-2012, row-number

We have a requirement to assign row number to all rows using following rule

- Row if pinned should have same row number
- Otherwise sort it by GMD

Example:

```
 ID  GMD   IsPinned 

 1   2.5    0        
 2    0     1        
 3    2     0        
 4    4     1        
 5    3     0
```

Should Output

```
ID  GMD   IsPinned  RowNo

5    3    0          1   
2    0    1          2  
1    2.5  0          3  
4    4    1          4  
3    2    0          5
```

Please Note row number for Id's 2 and 4 stayed intact as they are pinned with values of 2 and 4 respectively even though the GMD are not in any order
Rest of rows Id's 1, 3 and 5 row numbers are sorted using GMD desc

I tried using RowNumber SQL 2012 however, it is pushing pinned items from their position

Comment: but why do yoou need this??

Answer (score 1):

Here's a set-based approach to solving this. Note that the first [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is unnecessary if you already have a `Numbers` table in your database:

```
declare @t table (ID int,GMD decimal(5,2),IsPinned bit)
insert into @t (ID,GMD,IsPinned) values
(1,2.5,0), (2, 0 ,1), (3, 2 ,0), (4, 4 ,1), (5, 3 ,0)

;With Numbers as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) n from @t
), NumbersWithout as (
    select
        n,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) as rn
    from
        Numbers
    where n not in (select ID from @t where IsPinned=1)
), DataWithout as (
    select
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GMD desc) as rn
    from
        @t
    where
        IsPinned = 0
)
select
    t.*,
    COALESCE(nw.n,t.ID) as RowNo
from
    @t t
        left join
    DataWithout dw
        inner join
    NumbersWithout nw
        on
            dw.rn = nw.rn
        on
            dw.ID = t.ID
order by COALESCE(nw.n,t.ID)
```

Hopefully my naming makes it clear what we're doing. I'm a bit cheeky in the final `SELECT` by using a `COALESCE` to get the final `RowNo` when you might have expected a `CASE` expression. But it works because the contents of the `DataWithout` CTE is defined to only exist for unpinned items which makes the final `LEFT JOIN` fail.

Results:

```
ID          GMD                                     IsPinned RowNo
----------- --------------------------------------- -------- --------------------
5           3.00                                    0        1
2           0.00                                    1        2
1           2.50                                    0        3
4           4.00                                    1        4
3           2.00                                    0        5
```

---

Second variant that may perform better (but never assume, always test):

```
declare @t table (ID int,GMD decimal(5,2),IsPinned bit)
insert into @t (ID,GMD,IsPinned) values
(1,2.5,0), (2, 0 ,1), (3, 2 ,0), (4, 4 ,1), (5, 3 ,0)

;With Numbers as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) n from @t
), NumbersWithout as (
    select
        n,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) as rn
    from
        Numbers
    where n not in (select ID from @t where IsPinned=1)
), DataPartitioned as (
    select
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IsPinned ORDER BY GMD desc) as rn
    from
        @t
)
select
    dp.ID,dp.GMD,dp.IsPinned,
    CASE WHEN IsPinned = 1 THEN ID ELSE nw.n END as RowNo
from
    DataPartitioned dp
        left join
    NumbersWithout nw
        on
            dp.rn = nw.rn
order by RowNo
```

In the third CTE, by introducing the `PARTITION BY` and removing the `WHERE` clause we ensure we have all rows of data so we don't need to re-join to the original table in the final result in this variant.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("ID" int, "GMD" number, "IsPinned" int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 ("ID", "GMD", "IsPinned")
         VALUES (1, 2.5, 0)
    INTO Table1 ("ID", "GMD", "IsPinned")
         VALUES (2, 0, 1)
    INTO Table1 ("ID", "GMD", "IsPinned")
         VALUES (3, 2, 0)
    INTO Table1 ("ID", "GMD", "IsPinned")
         VALUES (4, 4, 1)
    INTO Table1 ("ID", "GMD", "IsPinned")
         VALUES (5, 3, 0)
SELECT * FROM dual
;


select * from (select  "ID","GMD","IsPinned",rank from(select m.*,rank()over(order by 
"ID" asc) rank from Table1 m where "IsPinned"=1)
union
(select "ID","GMD","IsPinned",rank from (select t.*,rank() over(order by "GMD" 
desc)-1 rank from (SELECT * FROM Table1)t)
where "IsPinned"=0) order by "GMD" desc) order by rank ,GMD;
```

output:

```
   2    0   1   1
   5    3   0   1
   1    2.5 0   2
   4    4   1   2
   3    2   0   3
```

Comment: Row numbers are distinct in the OPs expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (ID int, GMD numeric (18,2), IsPinned int);


INSERT INTO Table1 (ID,GMD, IsPinned)
         VALUES (1, 2.5, 0), 
                (2, 0, 1),
                (3, 2, 0),
                (4, 4, 1),
                (5, 3, 0)





   select *, row_number () over(partition by IsPinned order by (case when IsPinned =0 then GMD else id end) ) [CustOrder] from Table1
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the requirements - if `IsPinned` = 1 then the CustOrder should be the same as ID. If `IsPinned = 0` then the values should be incrementing ordered by GMD.

Answer (score 0):

This took longer then I thought, the thing is [row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) would take a part to resolve the query. We need to differentiate the row_numbers by id first and then we can apply the while loop or cursor or any iteration, in our case we will just use the while loop.

**dbo.test (you can replace test with your table name)**

```
1   2.5 False
2   0   True
3   3   False
4   4   True
6   2   False
```

Here is the query I wrote to achieve your result, I have added comment under each operation you should get it, if you have any difficultly let me know.

**Query**:

```
--user data table 
DECLARE @userData TABLE 
  ( 
     id        INT NOT NULL, 
     gmd       FLOAT NOT NULL, 
     ispinned  BIT NOT NULL, 
     rownumber INT NOT NULL 
  ); 
--final result table 
DECLARE @finalResult TABLE 
  ( 
     id           INT NOT NULL, 
     gmd          FLOAT NOT NULL, 
     ispinned     BIT NOT NULL, 
     newrownumber INT NOT NULL 
  ); 

--inserting to uer data table from the table test 
INSERT INTO @userData 
SELECT t.*, 
       Row_number() 
         OVER ( 
           ORDER BY t.id ASC) AS RowNumber 
FROM   test t 

--creating new table for ids of not pinned 
CREATE TABLE #ids 
  ( 
     rn  INT, 
     id  INT, 
     gmd FLOAT 
  ) 

-- inserting into temp table named and adding gmd by desc
INSERT INTO #ids 
            (rn, 
             id, 
             gmd) 
SELECT DISTINCT Row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    ORDER BY gmd DESC) AS rn, 
                id, 
                gmd 
FROM   @userData 
WHERE  ispinned = 0 

--declaring the variable to loop through all the no pinned items
DECLARE @id INT 
DECLARE @totalrows INT = (SELECT Count(*) 
   FROM   #ids) 
DECLARE @currentrow INT = 1 
DECLARE @assigningNumber INT = 1 

--inerting pinned items first
INSERT INTO @finalResult 
SELECT ud.id, 
       ud.gmd, 
       ud.ispinned, 
       ud.rownumber 
FROM   @userData ud 
WHERE  ispinned = 1 

--looping through all the rows till all non-pinned items finished
WHILE @currentrow <= @totalrows 
  BEGIN 
        --skipping pinned numers for the rows
      WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                   FROM   @finalResult 
                   WHERE  newrownumber = @assigningNumber 
                          AND ispinned = 1) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @assigningNumber = @assigningNumber + 1 
        END 

      --getting row by the number
      SET @id = (SELECT id 
                 FROM   #ids 
                 WHERE  rn = @currentrow) 

      --inserting the non-pinned item with new row number into the final result
      INSERT INTO @finalResult 
      SELECT ud.id, 
             ud.gmd, 
             ud.ispinned, 
             @assigningNumber 
      FROM   @userData ud 
      WHERE  id = @id       

      --going to next row
      SET @currentrow = @currentrow + 1 
      SET @assigningNumber = @assigningNumber + 1 
  END 

--getting final result
SELECT * 
FROM   @finalResult 
ORDER  BY newrownumber ASC 

--dropping table
DROP TABLE #ids
```

**Output:**

[image]